# Importing a Keras model into TensorFlow.js from Django Server

Tags: javascript, python, django, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to import a Keras model from my Django to a web browser.

This is how to fetch a Keras model from a web server

```
// JavaScript

import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://foo.bar/tfjs_artifacts/model.json');
```

It accepts URL as an argument. However the code inside this function sends another HTTP request for weights of a model. Namely **group1-shard1of1.bin**

I can write such view to import json file

```
def request_a_model(request):
    return render(request, ‚models/model.json’)
```

but what with subsequent request for binary files?

How can Django code handle these requests and send model.json file and weights as binary files?